# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el color de un texto en base al fondo en el que se encuentra? De manera tal que estos se contrasten

Tags: java-swing

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver en la captura, tengo un `JCheckBox` que al seleccionarlo te muestra una imagen, el problema es que cuando te muestra la imagen, se ve asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El color de la imagen hace que no se pueda apreciar el texto que tiene el `JCheckBox`. Me gustaría que el texto de alguna forma pudiera contrastar con el color que tiene la imagen de fondo. Hay otras soluciones como poner el `JCheckBox` fuera de la imagen, pero tendría que cambiar el diseño de mi programa.

Como referencia algo asi es el efecto que quiero que tenga:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay alguna forma de poder hacerlo? Como?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Opción 1:** Blanco y negro

Se puede solucionar de la siguiente manera, pero al final depende de si podes acceder a la imagen y al CheckBox para realizar el cambio, ya que lo probé y funciona correctamente...

Lo que hice fue crear un método que pida una imagen como parámetro y al final que devuelva un color blanco o negro dependiendo de cuanta oscuridad hay en la imagen.

Primero se tiene que convertir la imagen a un `BufferedImage` y aplicarle el tipo `TYPE_BYTE_BINARY`, este valor devuelve el `BufferedImage` con solo 2 colores, o blanco o negro.

Luego se crea 2 contadores, para contar cuantos pixeles claros y oscuros hay en total, recorriendo el `BufferedImage` simplemente se comprueba el valor actual recorrido con el valor del color negro, y si es igual entonces se aumenta el contador, si no el de los pixeles blancos.

Al final si hay mas pixeles blanco, devuelve el color negro, y viceversa.

```
/**
 * Devuelve un color blanco o negro dependiendo de la imagen de fondo.
 * 
 * @param image
 * @return
 */
public Color contrast(Image image) {
    BufferedImage buffered = toBufferedImage(image);
        
    int black = 0, white = 0;
        
    for (int x = 0; x < buffered.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < buffered.getHeight(); y++) {
            if(buffered.getRGB(x, y) == Color.BLACK.getRGB()) {
                black++;
            }else {
                white++;
            }
        }
    }
        
    System.out.println("Blanco: " + white + ", Negro: " + black);
    
    return (white > black) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE;
}

private BufferedImage toBufferedImage(Image image) {
    int width = image.getWidth(null);
    int height = image.getHeight(null);
    int argb = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY;
        
    BufferedImage buffered = new BufferedImage(width, height, argb);
        
    Graphics2D g2 = buffered.createGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g2.dispose(); 
        
    // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new ImageIcon(buffered));

    return buffered;
}
```

La manera de implementarlo seria obteniendo la imagen que se va a mostrar y pasársela al método, luego aplicar el color que retorne al texto del CheckBox

```
Color textColor = contrast.contrast(image);
checkbox.setForeground(textColor);
```

La imagen en blanco y negro la podes visualizar descomentando la linea del `JOptionPane` y la salida en consola es la cantidad de pixeles blancos y negros que hay en la imagen, en base a eso determina el color que debe retornar.

---

**Opción 2:** Colores

Para devolver un color que contraste con todos los colores de la imagen, podes aplicar el siguiente método:

A este punto conviene que crees una clase llamada `Contraste` por que ya se vuelve algo extenso, pero a coste de que devuelva colores y no solo blanco y negro.

Consiste en un pequeño método donde puedas realizar la mezcla de todos los colores de la imagen dinámicamente a partir de un array y construir el color invertido...

La inversión de color se realiza restando 255 a los valores RGB del color a invertir, por ejemplo invertir el color rojo seria así

```
255,0,0 -> (255-255, 255-0, 255-0) = new Color(0, 255, 255)
```

ref: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversi%C3%B3n_(imagen)

Para la mezcla de color, sin ir a temas complejos podrías realizar este algoritmo, que consigue una mezcla bastante aceptable:

Primero se necesita obtener los valores RGB en un array a partir del entero que devuelve `BufferedImage` con el método `getRGB(x, y)`, esto es una utilidad para realizar la mezcla de color en otro método

```
/*
 * Devuelve los valores RGBA en un array a partir del entero
 * que devuelve el método getRGB del BufferedImage, en un array
 * con la siguiente secuencia
 * 
 * [0] = Red
 * [1] = Green
 * [2] = Blue
 * [3] = Alpha
 */
private int[] getRGBBuffered(int color) {
    return new int[]{(color >> 16) & 0xFF, (color >> 8) & 0xFF, (color >> 0) & 0xFF, (color >> 24) & 0xFF};
}
```

Luego para realizar la mezcla podes utilizar este pequeño método, consiste en cargar un primer color `colors[0]`, y luego ir recorriendo el resto de la lista desde `i=1` mezclado los colores con ese ya mezclado, el resultado es la mezcla de todos los colores, al final se invierte el color con el método de inversión de color que te comente antes.

```
private Color blend(int[] colors) {
    int[] color = getRGBBuffered(colors[0]);
    int red = color[0], green = color[1], blue = color[2];
    
    for(int i = 1; i < colors.length; i++) {
        int[] rgb = getRGBBuffered(colors[i]);
        
        red = (red + rgb[0]) / 2;
        
        green = (green + rgb[1]) / 2;
        
        blue = (blue + rgb[2]) / 2;
    }
    
    return new Color(255-red, 255-green, 255-blue);
}
```

Ahora solo falta implementarlo al primer método de mi respuesta que es `contrast`, antes que nada el BufferedImage pasa a ser de `TYPE_BYTE_BINARY`, a uno de valores RGB con `TYPE_INT_ARGB` ya que ahora percibe los colores de la imagen.

```
/**
 * Devuelve un color que contraste con todos los colores de la imagen.
 * 
 * @param image
 * @return
 */
public Color contrast(Image image) {
    BufferedImage buffered = toBufferedImage(image);
    
    List<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (int x = 0; x < buffered.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < buffered.getHeight(); y++) {
            if(!colors.contains(buffered.getRGB(x, y))) {
                colors.add(buffered.getRGB(x, y));
            }
        }
    }
    
    return blend(colors.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray());
}
```

Con todo eso te devolverá un color para el texto que no se perderá con el fondo, recuerda que todo depende de los colores de la imagen, quizás tu imagen tiene 6 colores y el color devuelto contrasta con 5 de ellos notoriamente, pero con el 6to apenas se nota (siempre va haber contraste).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, si puedo acceder a las 2 cosas, pero existe alguna forma de que sirva también para los demás colores??

Comment: @IgnacioInzerilli Se puede, modifique mi respuesta para que devuelva un color que contraste con todos los de la imagen, en tus ejemplos muestras imágenes que tienen 1 solo color, lo cual es fácil de hacer, pero cuando la imagen tiene muchos colores es complicado determinar que color se debe usar, para estos casos se busca un color que se vea sobre todos los colores de la imagen o sobre la mayoría.